# How to return app version in terminal on osx

Tags: macos, terminal

I am needing to use app version in a .sh script on Mac osX 10.10 so that I can do a compare to another number so I can force an update or not.

So far I have this (I am using Firefox.app as an example)

```
FirefoxmdlsVersion= mdls -name kMDItemVersion /Applications/Firefox.app;
echo $FirefoxmdlsVersion
```

This returns `kMDItemVersion = "34.0"`which is a step in the right direction but I need just the number so that I can do my compare example `340`

Here is what I have attempted to do with a new variable but I dont get an error or output at all

```
FFV2=${FirefoxmdlsVersion//'kMDItemVersion ='}
FFV3=${FirefoxmdlsVersion:18:4}
```

I maybe going in the wrong direction here, but Ive looked a post and havent made any progress.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `tr` as well:

```
FirefoxmdlsVersion= mdls -name kMDItemVersion /Applications/Firefox.app | tr -d ".";
```

Which produces `3405` (From Firefox 34.0.5)

Comment: Instead of using `tr`, you can use the `-raw` flag: `FirefoxmdlsVersion= mdls -raw -name kMDItemVersion /Applications/Firefox.app`.

Comment: @icecream - The OP wished to remove the `.`'s and `-raw` does not do that. However `-raw` does remove everything else other than the number with dots (even the newline), so both `-raw` and `tr` produce just the digits if that is what is required.

Comment: This solution require to application be indexed by MacOSX spotlight.

Answer (score 14):

If you have Xcode and the developer tools installed, you can always use [PlistBuddy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/PlistBuddy.8.html)...

For example:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

gives me back the version number of "`1.10`" under Yosemite.

The Info.plist file of any app usually has a version under the "`CFBundleShortVersionString`" key.

Comment: Would this work inside of a loginhook script?  I was hoping that I wouldn't need to install anything on the client stations running the script.

Answer (score 6):

To add one more option to the list, you can also use the `defaults` tool.

For example:

`defaults read /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Info.plist CFBundleShortVersionString`

Will output the value of the `CFBundleShortVersionString` entry from Firefox's Info.plist file, e.g.: `74.0`

I prefer to use the `defaults` command because there are no preconditions to using it and the command is very simple.

Answer (score 2):

Shell:

```
plutil -p /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Info.plist | awk '/CFBundleShortVersionString/ {print substr($3, 2, length($3)-2)}'
```

Or Python:

```
import plistlib
plistlib.readPlist('/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Info.plist')['CFBundleShortVersionString']
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below command in the MAC Terminal

```
system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType |grep "Application Name" -A 8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Info.plist | grep -A1 CFBundleShortVersionString | grep string | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

This will go into the `Info.plist` for Firefox and return the version number for the bundle. Last thing it does is remove the tags from around the version for a clean output.