# How to get an application's version on macOS?

Tags: python, macos

I am writing a simple script using python to be used on macOS BigSur. I was wondering if there is a way to find the version of an application using python. I know it's possible on Windows using PyWin32 library, however, I could not find anything for MacOS.

Comment: You can find os shell command (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27595435/how-to-return-app-version-in-terminal-on-osx/47021504)) and [run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27595435/how-to-return-app-version-in-terminal-on-osx/47021504) it in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @sudden_appearance for the approach

```
import os
stream = os.popen('mdls -raw -name kMDItemVersion /Applications/Firefox.app')
targetVer = stream.read()
print(targetVer)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).